# Wordpress site stopped working after simply opening header.php in the wp-admin editor

Tags: wp-admin, encoding

I opened `header.php` inside the wp-admin editor and suddenly the actual site is filled with diamond shaped question marks. Admin area still works.

The weird thing is that I didn't even perform any edits to the file. In the matter of fact Wordpress told me that this file needs to be write-enabled before I can save changes to it...

What on earth could have happened here?

Comment: Could you provide link to a live site or at least screenshot demonstrating the issue? Clearly something went very wrong, but it is hard to make a good guess from this little of information.

Comment: Does the issue persist with a hard refresh of your page?

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to a corrupt `header.php` file. Try changing your theme, or replace your `header.php` file from backup.